# Additional baggage (computer equipment) on Qatar Airways -travelling from Yerevan (EVN) to Chennai(MAA)

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways, fragile-luggage

I am travelling with my PC, so the actual computer + case and monitor have their own cases ... That makes 2 pieces but they weigh only around 15 kg together.

In my booking i have 2 pieces - total 40 kg given.

Will they allow me to check-in an extra baggage along with my computer and monitor as an exception if the total weight is under 40 kg?

I am traveling from EVN - DOH - MAA, from Yerevan TO Chennai with a connection at Doha.

I want to know if this is possible or do I have to pay extra or any other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

[Qatar Airways baggage allowance](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/baggage/allowance.html) does vary according to your ticket class and route. Your route falls within

*Flights to and from all other destinations*
First Class : 50kg (110lb) and a maximum dimension of 300 cm (118in)
Business Class : 40kg (88lb) and a maximum dimension of 300 cm (118in)
Economy Class : 30kg (66lb) and a maximum dimension of 300 cm (118in)

You would need to calculate the maximum dimension of each piece (length + width + height), and add those two results to determine how much additional baggage you would be allowed to check before you would be charged [excess baggage fees](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/baggage/excess.html) by your carrier.